# How can I enable storeconfigs without using PuppetDB?

Tags: puppet

*Background:*

We are testing the catalog extensively with puppet-cucumber. I know that this project is no longer maintained by the original implementor, but it helps us to cover a whole manifest, integrating several modules. For individual modules, we use puppet-rspec. For the (rails) application we develop, we use jenkins to run the whole test-suite. I started using the same approach for the puppet testsuite. This was all fine until we added stored configurations and exported resources to our manifests. We use PuppetDB for that in production. So far everything is good.

*Problem:*

While running my tests, puppet complains that exported resources won't work without storeconfigs turned on.

How can I enable storeconfigs without using PuppetDB?

Here is the list of things I do not care about / can accept in a non-production-ready state:

- performance
- ruby versions
- gem versions
- persistence for a long time.

I do care about:

- portable setup (sqlite3 or memcache would be good, installing/configuring a full grown DB not so much)
- easily scriptable setup with one script (no puppet-run to prepare to test puppet, please)
- isolation (if possible. I don't want parallel test-runs to interfere with on another)

Comment: AFAIK there is no reasonable alternative to PDB for this purpose, however it would seem there should be a way to handle this case within rspec-puppet or puppet itself. Perhaps the approach should be to request for a sans-PDB setup to work, rspec-puppet isn't multi-node so having exported resources work fully seems unnecessary. Internally Puppet can collect and be aware of resources without storedconfigs 'working' it just seems like a missing feature. I would experiment with adding a terminus (storeconfigs_backend=dummy) that is a dummy terminus perhaps. I can probably help you on this path.

Comment: BTW, such a dummy terminus doesn't exist, it would need to be written. Its really about the catalog and resource terminus here: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb/tree/master/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector ... if you use those as a base, and have the save/find actions 'do nothing' or some such you might get some results.

Answer (score 1):

If youn don't want to use puppetdb, you can use sqlite as db adapter

```
[master]
storeconfigs = true
dbadapter = sqlite3
```